# Special representatives for elements of a quotient ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A=k[x,y,z,a]/I$, where $$I= \lbrace a^2(x+1)-z^2, ax(x+1)-yz, xz-ay,y^2-x^2(x+1) \rbrace$$

I'd like to show that each class $a \in A$ is represented by a unique polynomial $f_a$ with the following property: no monomial term of $f_a$ is divisible by $z^2, yz, xz$, or $y^2$.

What is a good strategy for proving such a claim (in particular, the uniqueness)?

Comment: This will follow from Macaulay's lemma (e.g., Proposition 3.10 in http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/subdiv-v7-long.pdf ) if you can show that $I$ is a Gröbner basis with respect to some monomial order and the leading terms of the four generators of $I$ are $z^2, yz, xz, y^2$.